# How to dynamically add columns for matrices in Python without using numPy?

Tags: python, matrix

I have some code where i have to build a matrix with python and add rows and columns with new occurrence of an attribute. I can add rows easily but how to add columns. I can't get more than 2 columns as of now. As of now I am trying to find a way without numpy to get this done.

this is what I have until now:

```
matrix = []
for(item in items):
    matrix.append([]) #This is how I add a new row dynamically
    matrix.append(item.name)

    #There may be more than one property for item 
    #I want to add all property names as columns, item names as rows 

    for(property in itemProperties):              
        matrix[items.index(item.name)].append(property.name)

     #How should I add more than one column ?
     #The above line is good only to add one column.
     #It doesn't crash but I can see only one property for each item in output
```

How can I add a column dynamically ?

Comment: may we see a bit more of your coded problem, please. This is a bit too brief and contextless.....

Comment: can you provide more than an empty list as it is not clear what you are asking

Comment: Can you guys check the updated code ? Thanks !!

Comment: That indexing call does not look very efficient, I have a feeling you are using the wrong container, a dictionary may be a much better idea using `item.name` as the key, I also think using mixed data types is going to give you headaches. You can also use a list comp in your code instead of your append approach

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, somehow I found this answer,

```
 sampleMatrix = [{}]
 for i in range(0,5):   # no.of rows
    sampleMatrix.append({})
    for j in range(0,5): #no. of columns
        sampleMatrix[i][j] = j #element at ith row jth column

 print(sampleMatrix)
```

This solves the problem.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest something like

```
for r in matrix:
     r.append(inital_value)
```

As far as I can see you just have to add an element in every row in the matrix.

Comment: Dear downvoter: please leave a comment why you do not think this answer was helpful.